# How to get output from powershell process

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

Here's the code

```
function RunPowershellAsAdmin($CommandToBeExecuted)
{
    If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
      {   
        #$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'" 
        Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "$CommandToBeExecuted" -Verbose
      }
 }
 RunPowershellAsAdmin("& { Import-Module WebAdministration; if(Test-Path 'IIS:\Sites\$Website_Name') { Remove-WebSite -Name  '$Website_Name'; } }")
```

-Verb and -RedirectStandardOutput are not in the same parameter, so i can not use -RedirectStandardOutput to get process output [as per answer from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247854/calling-powershell-exe-giving-parameter-set-errors).

I want to run the process in a hidden window, wait for it to return and get the error, output and exit code.

Is there any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to both RunAs in addition to redirecting any of the standard streams, you'll need to use the [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) and [System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) classes directly.  More information on how to handle the redirected stream can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
$startInfo = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$startInfo.FileName = "powershell"
$startInfo.Arguments = "& { Import-Module WebAdministration; ... }"
$startInfo.Verb = "runas"
$startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true

$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($startInfo)

$output = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

$process.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have tried suggestion but, throws an error like "Process should have elevated status to access IIS configure data".

Comment: Are you running your PowerShell session via Run As Administrator?

Comment: No i can,t run it as administrator. I want to run powershell using domain user credentials in release management server. I am using this for website deployment on different server.